# REGEX for html4

Tags: c#, html, unity-game-engine, html4

i want to parse html4 in C# (unity), using regEx, is there any RegEx that can help me ...??

Thanx

Comment: No. [See this answer for details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6150573)

Answer (score 1):

No. RegEx is a bad choice for HTML-parsing. Use [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead.